# How to not to use forEach statement twice

Tags: javascript, node.js

As you see I use forEach statement twice in

```
fileList.forEach((file) => {
    setFolder.forEach((folderName) => {
```

part.

At first I use for loop in setFolder part but it seems more awful.. So I change it to forEach statement again. But it looks something bad. I think there are better then this code. Any advices?

```
const fs = require("fs"); // Node.js file system module
const dir =
  "G:\\google drive"; // set path
let setFolder = [
  "A",
  "B",
  "C",
  "D",
  "E",
  "F",
];

/* Create new folder name with setFolder array */
setFolder.forEach((folder) => {
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir + "\\complete\\" + folder)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir + "\\complete\\" + folder);
  }
});

fs.readdir(dir, async function (error, fileList) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(fileList);
  fileList.forEach((file) => {
    setFolder.forEach((folderName) => {
      if (file.startsWith(folderName)) {
        fs.rename(
          dir + "\\" + file,
          dir + "\\complete\\" + folderName + "\\" + file,
          function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(`${file} move to ${folderName} complete`);
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're doing. Does each `file` have multiple `folderName` properties? If so, a nested loop is appropriate.

Comment: Is this code not working as expected in some way?  "But it looks something bad" isn't really a description of a problem.  Nested loops aren't *inherently* bad.  It's possible that your design is flawed, but we don't know what you're designing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can use the .find() method of Javascript array to find the file which starts with the folder name.

Example:

```js
 fileList.forEach((file) => {
    const correspondingFolder = setFolder.find(folderName => file.startsWith(folderName));
    if (correspondingFolder) {
    // ....
    }
  });
```

Here is the complete docs of find() method: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find